# What is waiting on a dns look up?

Tags: web, dns, host

I have a website that seems to have a really slow dns look up. It can take anywhere from 2.7 sec to 18 sec. But I was playing around with it and went to the page and it took 48.91 sec to do the dns lookup and all of the time it was "waiting" Can someone explain what the different stages are and if it's my website that is causing the waiting problem or if its the hosting company? The website is a Joomla website and the hosting provider is NetworkSolutions.

Comment: Is your server trying to do reverse lookups of the client IP?

Comment: Is `host www.yourdomain.com` slow?

Comment: I don't think NS is using a reverse look up. What do you mean you say is host www.yourdomain.com slow? are you taking about when i go to the url all writen out? http://www.mydomain.com/

Comment: if it helps inside me dns records it in the A record is just the ip address of the server that hosts the account?

Comment: I mean when you're in a Unix shell and type the command `host www.yourdomain.com`, replacing `yourdomain` with your actual domain. This will do a DNS lookup of your server name. And the reverse lookup question is about the webserver, not the NS. It might help if you gave your actual URL, so we can try it ourselves and see what's happening.

Comment: The delay is happening when the webserver responds to the HTTP GET request for the home page, not in DNS lookup, as far as I can tell. All the other documents (CSS, JS, images) download quickly, so it's not a general server issue -- it's something in that main page that takes a long time to respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an excellent article and talk by Tom Daly regarding speeding up DNS lookups and decreasing TTB (Time to Byte).

http://dyn.com/blog/time-to-first-dns-query-response-performance-behind-the-byte/

http://youtu.be/iCfuKZUyTko